# What's the point of document.defaultView?

Tags: javascript, dom

What's the point of `document.defaultView`?

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.defaultView):

> In browsers returns the window object associated with the document or null if none available.

Code like the following (from [PPK's site](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html#link7)) makes use of `document.defaultView`:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

Code like this can be found in other places, like David Mark's *My Library*. I'm not sure if people are just copying from PPK or some other source or coming up with this independently, but I don't understand it.

My question is, what is the point of using `document.defaultView` in cases like this? Wouldn't it be easier to write this as follows:

```
function getStyle(element, styleProp) {
    if (element === ''+element) element = document.getElementById(element);
    return element.currentStyle ? element.currentStyle[styleProp] :
           getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
}
```

What does `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` do that `window.getComputedStyle` or simply `getComputedStyle` does not?

---

cwolves' answer got me thinking in the right direction. The original function is silly, missing the point of `defaultView`. My proposal above is less silly, but also missing the point of `defaultView`. Here's my new proposal:

```
function getStyle(element, styleProp) {
    var view = element.ownerDocument && element.ownerDocument.defaultView ?
                element.ownerDocument.defaultView : window;

    return view.getComputedStyle ? 
                view.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp) : 
            element.currentStyle ? 
                element.currentStyle[styleProp] : null;
}
```

The element itself must be passed in, not the id. I think this is probably to be preferred anyway. This gets the document containing the node, and the window associated with it. It has a fallback to the current window's `getComputedStyle` if `ownerDocument` or `defaultView` are broken (I vaguely remember `getComputedStyle` being around before `defaultView`).  This is probably closer to the intended use of `defaultView`.

Comment: How about this? `documentView` is a circular reference to `window` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183555/whats-the-point-of-document-defaultview

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not positive on this, but I imagine that it's the result of fixing a bug from either trying to run code on a detached document (i.e. something that exists in memory but is not in the page) or trying to run on a document in a different window (e.g. an iframe or a popup).

According to your quote, when `document.defaultView` is run on a document that is NOT the current document, you will get the associated window object, thus `document.documentView.getComputedStyle !== getComputedStyle` since they are in different contexts.

In short, I believe it's akin to `document.window` which doesn't exist.

Comment: So would another way of phrasing that be, it's only useful if you don't already have a handle to the window/global associated with the document?

Comment: not necessarily -- As I said, you can have several different documents (iframes) so it's a link to that specific window (e.g. `iframe.contentWindow` vs `window` vs `iframe2.contentWindow`).  A document can also be moved around, so even if you store that original link it can get changed.  This is, I believe, a safe way to reference `current window` from `document`

Comment: You're right. Updating the question with a new proposal for how the function should look.

Comment: Does the stuff I added at the bottom of the question look right to you?

Answer (score 15):

The OP asks the question, "What's the point of `document.defaultView`", and the answer really doesn't have anything to do with getComputedStyle.  The `document.defaultView` property is simply a way of obtaining the `window` object if one has a reference to the `document` object contained in that `window`.  There are cases where the `window` object you are seeking to reference (or `defaultView`) is not in the same window scope as the code you are running.

One example of this is if you have a reference to the `document` object in an iframe, and wish to conveniently get a reference to the `window` object of that iframe.

Another case might be where you are running in privileged context in the browser scope (eg, chrome code in Firefox), and you happen to have a reference to the `document` object of a tabbrowser, or another window.

Or, as Dagg Nabbit points out, if in any of these cases you have a reference to an element within the window, you could access the parent `window` of that element through `element.ownerDocument.defaultView`

Answer (score 4):

According to [MDN `getComputedStyle` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle#defaultView),

> In many code samples online, `getComputedStyle` is used from the
>   `document.defaultView` object.
>
> In nearly all cases, this is needless, as
>   `getComputedStyle` exists on the `window` object as well.
>
> It's likely the
>   defaultView pattern was some combination of
>
> 1. folks not wanting to write a spec for window and
> 2. making an API that was also usable in Java.
>
> However, there is [a single case](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/524#issuecomment-2241183) where the `defaultView`'s method
>   must be used: when using Firefox 3.6 to access framed styles.

Comment: `defaultView` is useful because you can do `someElement.ownerDocument.defaultView` and it will still work if the element came from another document/window, like a frame or a `window.open` or whatever. The usual examples you see floating around seem to have missed this. I tried to go back and explain it in the question after I figured it out.

Comment: @DaggNabbit As the MDN article says, this was just for Firefox 3.6. Now you can just use `window` and it also works: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WQYbL/)

Comment: What really threw me about PPK and DM's examples was they used `defaultView` in a way that was equivalent to using `window`, because they just used the global `document` property instead of the document associated with the element, so it wasn't doing anything useful anyway AFAICT.

Comment: @Dagg Nabbit: Your first comment (eg `someElement.ownerDocument.defaultView`) is really the best answer to the question of your post (IMO, and also the most meaningful), why don't post it as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 3):

It is simply an abstraction as far as I can tell, just in case any user agents pop up with a DOM implementation, but don't provide a view in the form of a window. See [Views](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Views/views.html) in DOM level 2.

Comment: I don't believe any such UA's exist?

Comment: DOM 2 Views is obsolete. The `defaultView` property is defined in the HTML standard now.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Interesting. Seems they moved it out of DOM 3 altogether and into HTML. I'm having a hard time navigating whatwg.org right now though, could you provide a link? :|

Comment: @BoltClock It's one sentence: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-document-defaultview